# Как получить список активных тегов из связанных таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица tags и article_tags, в которой указано в какой статье какой тег используется. Мне нужно вывести таблицей информацию по тегам, которая должна включать колонку 'состояние', чтобы узнать используется тег или нет.

Есть два варианта реализации колонки 'состояние'. Нужно знать, какой будет лучше и быстрее.
Чтобы было проще, попытаюсь описать действия словами.

ПЕРВЫЙ вариант включает такие действия:
1) Выборка всех тэгов из бд в массив `$tags`
2) В `foreach` перебираю `$tags` и создаю список $tagid из `tag_id`
3) Выборка всех записей из `article_tags WHERE tag_id IN ($tagid)` в массив `$art_tags`
4) В `foreach` перебираю `($tags as $row)`. Внутри цикла вывожу нужную мне инфу по тегам + перебираю в `foreach ($art_tags as $val)` и в этом переборе проверяю через наличие id тега в `if(in_array($row['id'], $val)) $status = 1; break;`

ВТОРОЙ вариант включает такие действия:
1) Выборка всех тэгов из бд в массив `$tags`
2) В `foreach` перебираю `($tags as $row)`. Внутри цикла вывожу нужную мне инфу по тегам + на каждой итерации цикла делаю выборку из таблицы `article_tags`, и проверяю, если, что то вернуло то `Status = 1`.

В первом варианте больше действий, но он меня подкупил тем, что не приходится делать выборку из `article_tags` на каждом этапе цикла, как во 2 варианте. 
Какой по вашему мнению лучший?

Comment: Ни один из вышеперечисленных методов. Любую информацию из БД надо стараться получить одним запросом. Например что то типа `select T.tag_id, count(A.article_id) cnt from tags T left join article_tags A on A.tag_id=T.tag_id group by T.tag_id` даст список всех тегов и в колонке CNT даст количество статей с данным тегом. когда оно 0 - значит не используется. Если добавить к запросу `having count(A.article_id)=0` получим только те теги которые нигде не используются. Хотя именно не используемые можно получить и другими методами

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня  в проекте используется самописный конструктор запросов, который не поддерживает джоины. Перейти на sql запросы не могу. Так, что надо выбрать из этих вариантов

Comment: Переписать конструктор запросов. Это вообще сложно назвать конструктором, если он не поддерживает join. Как вариант - сделать в БД view содержащую подходящий запрос и в приложении сделать тупо select * from view_name

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автору нужен костыль для изначально кривого решения, что делает вопрос абсолютно бесполезным для кого бы то ни было.

Answer (score 1):

Учим SQL

```
SELECT tags.*, count(ta.tag_id) AS active 
FROM tags LEFT JOIN tags_articles AS ta ON tags.id=ta.tag_id
GROUP BY tags.id
```

Comment: к сожалению джоины нельзя использовать

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets ЧЕГО-ЧЕГО?!

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets если у вас самописный конструктор, то сделайте метод `.raw(string query)`. Его **всегда** делают самым первым, потому что конструктор нельзя просто взять и разом написать на чистовую, всегда приходится отходить на шаг назад в сложных случаях.

Comment: Конструктор не я писал, я всего лишь поддерживаю чужой код. Как просят, так и делаю

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets ну тогда и не надо заморочиваться. Как выше сказали, оба варианта кривые, так что не надо искать какой лучше. Подбрось монетку и не морочь себе голову.

Comment: Ну ок, уже выбрал 2, он отработал в 10 раз быстрее

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets А идея с view почему не подошла. отлично же отработает и не надо кучу кода на php клепать

Comment: @Mike на самом деле про конструктор - это всего лишь отмазка. На самом деле причина в том, что средний пользователь пхп до судорог боится всего нового. И загадочное view в БД также относится к этой категории. В видеоуроках с руселлера ничего про вью нет - а значит никакой силой нельзя заставить хомячка хотя бы поинтересоваться такой возможностью. Он скорее наплетет что структура базы тоже под запретом :)

Comment: @Mike Если я правильно понял, то вы предлагаете записать запрос в бд? где об этом можно почитать? Просто смахивает немного на индусский код..

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets Например https://habrahabr.ru/post/47031/ (вторая ссылка из гугла). Вообще просто `create view ABC as запрос-который-тут-в-ответе`. Все, после этого select * from ABC даст то, что дает такой запрос